# Why JsDuck ignores excluded directory?

Tags: jsduck

I use JsDusk

- Version : JSDuck 5.3.4 (Ruby 1.8.7)
- OS: Linux ( CentOS 6 )

I want to exclude some directories, but it doesn't work.

```
 --exclude="/Doc/Project1/application/,/Doc/Project1/docs/,/Doc/Project1/docUtil/"
```

Actually it should works. Here is the  [jsDuck Code](https://github.com/senchalabs/jsduck/commit/e770a60b62137c7caf521de60e803eae8f4cb80d) .

I start jsDuck in a script with the command below.

```
find /Doc/Project1/ -name '*.js' | xargs jsduck --output=/Doc/DocSrc/jsdoc --exclude=/Doc/Project1/application/ext,/Doc/Project1/application/,/Project1/docs,/Doc/Project1/docUtil,/Doc/Project1/framework,/jawaDoc/Project1/info
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The commit you're referring to is included to JSDuck 6.0 beta, but you're using 5.3.4.

You can install the beta with:

```
$ gem install jsduck --prerelease
```

Comment: Thank you, but how can I realise this in 5.3.4 ? Is there not other way?

Comment: In JSDuck 5 you can just use the `--exclude` option multiple times to specify multiple paths. The only thing that JSDuck 6 added was the ability to have comma-separated list of paths.